# Android source and merging branches

Tags: android, merge, branch

I've been learning to develop against the Android source tree, and while things are going well I'm not sure I've completed things in the most efficient way to merge into future versions.

**Background:** Android has many repositories that fit together. In some cases, a repo uses branches with names like "android-5.0.0_r6" to delineate a specific release. In other cases, that branch doesn't exist, instead, a tag exists with the name "android-5.0.0_r6".

**My method:** What I've done is create a new branch, called "nowsci-5.0.0_r6" based off the branch or tag (depending on which that repo had) for the repositories I needed to modify. I then made my changes, and pointed the android manifest at my new repos and everything seems to work fine.

**My question:** What should I do when "android-5.0.0_**r7**" rolls out? Is there an easy way to create a new branch of "nowsci-5.0.0_r7" and merge my modifications from r6 into r7? Or should I have done this completely different?

Here's one of the repos for example: https://github.com/Fmstrat/platform_frameworks_base

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow their lollipop-release branch instead of the android-5.0.0_rX branches.

Comment: So, just so I'm clear before marking this an answer, does this mean that the lollipop-release branch is updated each time the android-5.0.0_rX tag is updated? And if the official r6 tag is for the Nexus 4, it auto-updating to r7 won't hurt compiling for the Nexus 4, right? Actually, to ask the first part of this more specifically: Does lollipop-release = android-5.0.0_r6 without any changes up until the android-5.0.0_r7 tag is created?

Comment: And, one more, the platform_manifest (https://github.com/android/platform_manifest) does not have a lollipop-release branch. Is there a specific branch I should follow there?

Comment: Marking this as answered after comparing the latest android-5.0.0_r7 tag to the lollipop-release branch: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/compare/lollipop-release...android-5.0.0_r7